# Need to convert JSON format to another json format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Need to convert below request format by using javascript to output format.

Request:

```
{
  "patientId": "1234",
  "patientName": "Sai",
  "patientFname": "Kumar",
  "patientLname": "Gadi",
  "city": "",
  "zipcode":null,
  "state":" "

}
```

Need to convert as below format but we need to check object keyvalue of the element should not be null or " "(no space) or ""(not empty) then only we need to print the object name and its values as below format:

Output:

```
[
 {
  "propertyName": "patientId",
  "propertyValue": "1234"
 },
 {
   "propertyName": "patientName",
   "propertyValue": "Sai"
 },
 {
  "propertyName": "patientFname",
  "propertyValue": "Kumar"
  },
  {
   "propertyName": "patientLname",
    "propertyValue": "Gadi"
   }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use `map` and `filter` on `Object.entries`:

```js
const data = {
  "patientId": "1234",
  "patientName": "Sai",
  "patientFname": "Kumar",
  "patientLname": "Gadi",
  "city": "",
  "zipcode": null,
  "state": " "
};

const newData = Object.entries(data).filter(([, v]) => ![undefined, null, ""].includes(typeof v == "string" ? v.trim() : v)).map(([key, value]) => ({
  propertyName: key, 
  propertyValue: value
}));

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: This is nice. It's probably not an issue in this case, but might be in others — this will filter out the number `0`.

Comment: Whoops @MarkMeyer - I will fix that straight away.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I have fixed that issue, any better?

Comment: Oh yes @Shidersz that would be easier - I will do that.

Comment: @Shidersz Fixed that as well.

Comment: Yeah, looks good to me. Not sure why someone filter the need to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simle way to do it:

```
const obj = {
  "patientId": "1234",
  "patientName": "Sai",
  "patientFname": "Kumar",
  "patientLname": "Gadi",
  "city": "",
  "zipcode":null,
  "state":" "
};
const newArr = [];

for (let key in obj) {
  if (obj[key] && obj[key].trim()) {
    newArr.push({
      propertyName: key,
      propertyValue: obj[key]
    });
  }
}

console.log(newArr);
```

First, you iterate through the enumerable properties of the object. Within each iteration, you check if the value is not null or empty spaces. If there is a proper value, it will push the new object to the resulting array.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a  lot for the solution.But the if condition is not getting executed when we are sending "state":" "(with space).

Comment: Hey, just to get you right, am I supposed to return the object into the array if there are only spaces?

Comment: That is because `obj[key].trim()` removes spaces from `state: '" "`, cauing it to be state: "". Therefore, that if condition will check for that too.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) would be appropriate here. This way you do not have to call `Array` functions consecutively, just to loop through your array multiple times (ie: `Array.map()`+`Array.filter()`).

```js
let obj = {
  "patientId": "1234",
  "patientName": "Sai",
  "patientFname": "Kumar",
  "patientLname": "Gadi",
  "city": "",
  "zipcode": null,
  "state": " "
};

let res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (![undefined, null, ''].includes(typeof value === 'string' ? value.trim() : '')) {
    acc.push({
      propertyName: key,
      propertyValue: value
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Object.entries` and `reduce`

```js
let obj = {
  "patientId": "1234",
  "patientName": "Sai",
  "patientFname": "Kumar",
  "patientLname": "Gadi",
  "city": "",
  "zipcode":null,
  "state":" "
}

let op = Object.entries(obj).reduce((op,[key,value])=>{
  if((value||'').trim()){
    op.push({
    'propertyName' : key,
    'propertyValue': value
   })
  }
  return op
},[])

console.log(op)
```